# Apply monotone convergence to show that moments don't exist

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2I_d)$ with $\sigma^2\geq0$. For every $t \in \mathbb R$ satisfying $2t\sigma^2<1$ we have

$$\mathbb E[\exp(t|Y|^2)]=\frac{1}{(1-2t\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\exp\bigg(\frac{t|\mu|^2}{1-2t\sigma^2}\bigg)$$

where $|.|^2$ is the square of the euclidean norm.

Why does this imply that $$\mathbb E[\exp(t|Y|^2)]=\infty$$ if $2t\sigma^2\geq 1$?
Apparently one can show this using monoton convergence

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{E}[\exp(t|Y|^2)]$ is a monotonically increasing function of $t$. So:

$$\limsup_{\tau \uparrow 1/(2\sigma^2)}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\tau|Y|^2)]   \leq \mathbb{E}[\limsup_{\tau \uparrow 1/(2\sigma^2)}\exp(\tau|Y|^2)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\exp(t|Y|^2)]$$

for $t \geq 1/(2\sigma^2)$ where the first inequality is from fatou's lemma and the second from monotonicity. So if we can show that the LHS is $\infty$ then we are done. This is clear from the expression you have given above for the expectation.